# Enable touchpad pointer movement when second finger touch

Tags: 14.10, touchpad, asus

*ASUS X555L*

*Ubuntu 14.04.1 Desktop*

When I drag a finger over my MacBook's touchpad, pointer moves even if a second finger touches it.

Now, when I touch the touchpad on my ASUS laptop with a second finger pointer immediately stops moving.

How can I configure the touchpad to imitate MacBook's behaviour?